# How to do row-column transformation / Pivoting in Python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have written the below code in Python

```
import pandas as pd


data = {'Mnth':["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "April","May"],         
       'Income':["80","90","60", "30", "50"]} 

df = pd.DataFrame(data) 

print(df)
```

which gives the result as

[image]

I am looking for a transformation such that

```
Jan    Feb  Mar  April   May
---    ---  ---  -----   ---- 

80     90   60     30    50
```

I have tried with Pivot function as under

```
pivot  =df.pivot(index ='Mnth', columns ='Income') 

print(pivot)
```

but the result is

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [April, Feb, Jan, Mar, May]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Method 1: [`DataFrame.set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) + [`DataFrame.transpose`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html)

```
new_df=df.set_index('Mnth').T
print(new_df)
```

**Output**

```
Mnth   Jan Feb Mar April May
Income  80  90  60    30  50
```

---

You can use [`DataFrame.rename_axis`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) to remove the name of the columns (`Mnth`) and [`DataFrame.reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) to reset the DataFrame index

```
new_df=df.set_index('Mnth').T.rename_axis(columns=None).reset_index(drop=True)
print(new_df)
```

**Output**

```
  Jan Feb Mar April May
0  80  90  60    30  50
```

---

## Method 2: [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html):

```
df['Income']=df['Income'].astype(int)
new_df=df.pivot_table(columns='Mnth',values='Income')
print(new_df)
```

---

**Output**

```
Mnth    April  Feb  Jan  Mar  May
Income     30   90   80   60   50
```

---

**pivot_table with str type:**

it is necessary to change the default aggfunc which is to add:

```
new_df=df.pivot_table(columns='Mnth',values='Income',aggfunc=lambda x: ' '.join(x))
print(new_df)

Mnth   April Feb Jan Mar May
Income    30  90  80  60  50
```

Comment: thanks a lot!!!. Just out of curiosity, any way to put under line after the headers ..please....

Comment: Ok...please look at the output which I have mentioned in my question ..like after the month names (Jan, Feb etc...), I have made an underline - so is that possible ? I mean any option is there which we may have to set ? please...

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to perform that underline with some panda method

Comment: I didn't find nothing here :(: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/options.html